# Maven Jaxb2 plugin throwin error "undefined element declaration 's:schema' "

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, wsdl2java, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to generate the classes using maven jaxb2 plugin . However I am receiving the below exception :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://someIP/dummywsdl.asmx?wsdl; lineNumber: 32; columnNumber: 41; undefined element declaration 's:schema'
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$1.reportError(ParserContext.java:180)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.reportError(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:175)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.resolve(DelayedRef.java:110)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.run(DelayedRef.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.getResult(ParserContext.java:135)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.getResult(XSOMParser.java:214)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadWSDL(ModelLoader.java:412)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:170)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:50)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:488)
at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:311)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:352)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:197)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

After searching , I came to know that below 2 declaration in wsdl is causing the issue :

```
<s:element ref="s:schema"/>
<s:any/>
```

In one of the post , I found that If I change the above 2 lines with the below given line , then plugin is generating the files without any issue :

```
<s:any  minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" />
```

Below is the plugin configuration that I am using :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>com.abc</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://someIP/dummywsdl.asmx?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Is there any other way to resolve the issue without changing the WSDL , as this is a client WSDL , and I don't want to store it at my local with the above changes.

Answer (score 2):

Your schema seems to be invalid. So no, XJC won't compile it unless you fix the error.

As a workaround you can create a local copy of your schema and fix this copy. The you can create a catalog file which would "rewrite" the global URL ``` http://someIP/dummywsdl.asmx?wsdl`` into your local ```dummywsdl.asmx_wsdl`:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://someIP/dummywsdl.asmx?wsdl" "dummywsdl.asmx_wsdl"
```

See [Using catalogs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs) for more info.